# Ocelot Gateway authentication with OKTA

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, okta, ocelot

I am newbie to Identity Server. I am actually trying to authenticate JWT token generated by Okta provider from Ocelot gateway and allow access to the underlying API once the authentication is successful.

I can actually generate ID and Access token successfully using Postman. But I use the token to pass to Ocelot gateway is always show `401 unauthorized` error.

Here's the code from Ocelot gateway.

**Code**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
 .AddAuthentication()
 .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
 {
     options.Audience = "api://default"; // Okta Authorization server Audience
     options.Authority = "https://dev-12345678.okta.com/"; // Okta Authorization Issuer URI URL e.g. https://{subdomain}.okta.com/oauth2/{authidentifier}
     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
 });
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("scp");
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Add("scp", "scope");
        services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication().UseOcelot().Wait();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would review the order of the items in the Configure method. I would put UseRouting as one of the first items, like:

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseOcelot();
```

Do look at the existing examples in Github by doing this [search](https://github.com/search?q=UseOcelot%20%20UseAuthentication%20UseAuthorization&type=code)